# Staging vs Production slot - Azure Web app deployment

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-app-service-plans

My application has two app service plans: Non Prod and Prod. We are using NonProd for development and testing. And, Prod for Production. However, it's found that, the Prod has only one slot (that is, no staging slot present).

I read this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/deploy-staging-slots and recommended the infra to create a staging slot in the Prod app service plan. However, got the answer that are multiple things has to be changed if they are making a staging slot. For example, during swap the stage URL will replace the Production URL and they need to change DNS to map those. Are DNS change required?

Per my knowledge, this should not be the case.

My question is, is it that, during swap (due to some different configurations) the production URL will be replaced by the stage URL?  Also, is there any documentation, which will clarify and confirm what things will change and what will not? What all team's involvement required considering real customer application going to Prod?

As per my knowledge, the best recommended way is to create a stage and swap, this is not that difficult and should be completed in 5 mins (if proper access is there).

Comment: Please check these documents for [setting up slot](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/deploy-staging-slots) and [Which slot settings are swapped](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/deploy-staging-slots#which-settings-are-swapped)

Answer (score 3):

> For example, during swap the stage URL will replace the Production URL and they need to change DNS to map those. - Are DNS change required?

No DNS changes are required.
The production URL will point to the new version after the swap.

Configuration is one thing you have to check, by default configuration settings will move with the slot.
So any settings that you want to keep in a slot, you need to mark as "sticky"/slot-specific.

If you go to the App Service -> Configuration, you can click Edit for a setting:

[image: Application settings list with delete and edit buttons]

Then you can check *Deployment slot setting* if you want the setting to be specific to that slot and not move during swap:

[image: Setting editor with Name and Value fields and a checkbox for deployment slot setting]

You can see what happens during a swap here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/deploy-staging-slots#what-happens-during-a-swap.

What settings are swapped: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/deploy-staging-slots#which-settings-are-swapped

> Settings that are swapped:
>
> ```
> General settings, such as framework version, 32/64-bit, web sockets
> App settings (can be configured to stick to a slot)
> Connection strings (can be configured to stick to a slot)
> Handler mappings
> Public certificates
> WebJobs content
> Hybrid connections *
> Virtual network integration *
> Service endpoints *
> Azure Content Delivery Network *
> ```
>
> Features marked with an asterisk (*) are planned to be unswapped.
>
> Settings that aren't swapped:
>
> ```
> Publishing endpoints
> Custom domain names
> Non-public certificates and TLS/SSL settings
> Scale settings
> WebJobs schedulers
> IP restrictions
> Always On
> Diagnostic settings
> Cross-origin resource sharing (CORS)
> ```

Comment: Thank you for your response. Could you please elaborate on this : "So any settings that you want to keep in a slot, you need to mark as "sticky"/slot-specific."?

Comment: One more question, are creating a extra stage slot required extra cost?

Comment: I added some screenshots for where you can make settings slot-specific. Extra cost should not happen as you pay per VM instance in app service plan, not app.

Comment: Unless of course you are running on a tier that does not support deployment slots. In that case you would need to upgrade the app service plan, which would mean higher cost.

Comment: Just to add here to if you are using Managed Identities on your app services each slot will have a different identity.  This would lead to provision access both to the main slot and the staging slot.